# AWS - Script to create EC2 snapshots and automatically rename them

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rename, parsing

I'm currently trying to setup a script (using AWS CLI from an Ubuntu server) that will do the following:

- Create a snapshot of every existing volume. Those volumes already have a NAME tag (Like SERVER1, SERVER1DATA, SERVER2, SERVER2DATA etc).
- Rename those snapshots taken with the same tag NAMES (so then, on the AWS console i could filter them by date and would be able to easily identificate them).

The automatic rename is my main issue here.

I've been toying with ec2-describe-volumes , ec2-create-snapshot and ec2addtag commands but my scripting is not that good. So far i've been able to setup this by creating a list with VOLUME NAME and NAME TAG (those parameters are then taken by the ec2addtag) but i would have to manually update that list every time i add or remove a volume on the environment.

Any help will be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand your question completely, but if what you want is to be able to generate a list of your volumes, along with name tags, something like this might work:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --query "Tags[*].{Name:Value,ResourceId:ResourceId}" --filters "Name=key,Values=Name"  --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=volume" --output json
```

Basically what that says is "Give me the resource id and the value of the tag "name" for every resource of type "Volume".  In this case, I specified json as the output.  You may also specify "text" or "table" depending on your needs.

Another approach:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}" --output text
```

This would return a list of your volumes.  If you piped this to a text file, the file would just contain a list of volume identifiers - one per line.

You could then get the Name tag for each volume in the list with something like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --query "Tags[*].{Name:Value,ResourceId:ResourceId}" --filters "Name=key,Values=Name"  --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=volume" --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=vol-2e293949" --output json
```

This is basically saying "give me the resource id and the value of the tag name for the specified id vol-2e293949.

As you can see the CLI commands can be hard to read and the filtering and querying is a bit difficult.  (These examples use a recent version of the AWS [CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/))

Comment: Your input was exactly what i needed, it's indeed hard to me to filter the output from the AWS CLI but with those commands i'll have it much easier. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `create-snapshots` may be more useful here

`aws ec2 create-snapshots
  --instance-specification InstanceId=$INSTANCEID,ExcludeBootVolume=boolean
  --description "$DESCRIPTION"
  --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=string,Tags=[{Key=string,Value=string},{Key=string,Value=string}]'
  --region $REGION`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-snapshots.html

Answer (score 4):

As for extracting the snapshot ID from your create-snapshot command, you can do it without needing awk/sed/grep/etc. by using a few CLI features (query and output).

For example:

```
$ SNAP_ID=`aws ec2 create-snapshot --cli-input-json file://$temp_file --query 'SnapshotId' --output text`
$
$ echo "snap id: "$SNAP_ID
snap id: snap-aaaabbbb
$
$ aws ec2 create-tags --resources $SNAP_ID --tags Key=Name,Value=$SOME_NAME
$
```

Note that with an output of json instead of "text" it wraps the returned snapshot id with double quotes per JSON standard.

Answer (score 1):

A while back I wrote [this bash script](https://github.com/dannosaur/sysadmin/blob/master/backups/backup_ebs.sh) to do exactly this for me. Basically, you install it on each EC2 instance that you want to back up, and providing you give it a private key, a certificate file and the EC2 API tools, this will self-discover the instance ID, the volumes attached to it, and create a snapshot for each volume.

You must tag the volumes with `Name` and `Device`. `Name` is just a user-friendly name that appears in the snapshot's description. `Device` is is the actual device name on the server. `/dev/sdf` for instance. Finally, it will rotate your snapshots once a predefined limit has been reached. The default is 50. When the 51st snapshot is created, the oldest one will be deleted.

Comment: Wow! Great job there, it might give me a few ideas on my own. Thanks a lot for sharing this!

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}" --output text > /tmp/volumes

for i in $(cat /tmp/volumes); do

aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id $i | awk {'print $2'} | grep snap* | sed 's/\"//g'|sed 's/\,//g' > /tmp/snapname

SNAPENAME=$(cat /tmp/snapname)

TAGNAME=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --query "Tags[*].{Name:Value,ResourceId:ResourceId}" --filters "Name=key,Values=Name" --filters "Name=resource-type,Values=volume" --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$i" --output text | awk '{ print $1 }') 

sleep 5

aws ec2 create-tags --resources $SNAPENAME --tags Key=Name,Value=$TAGNAME >/dev/null

done
```

It's a little bit messy and perhaps unnecessary long, but it does what required: Create a snapshot of all available volumes and (if those had NAME tags) then rename them with those NAME tags.